# convert associate array to normal array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

This is my array

```
$array = array(
        1 => 'A', 
        2 => 'B', 
        3 => 'C', 
        4 => 'D', 
        5 => 'E', 
    );
```

I want to Convert it like this

```
array('A','B','C','D','E');
```

Answer (score 0):

use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function:

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

i hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

simply use array_values function:

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Use `array_values`.

If you want to differentiate, then you can use:

```
$array1 = array_keys($array);
$array2 = array_values($array);
```

Comment: Man, All arrays have keys. See [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)